# How can I prove the conclusion in this example?

Tags: real-analysis

Assume that $A_n(n=0,1,2,\cdots)$ is a sequence of sets:
$$A_{2n+1}=[0,2-\frac{1}{2n+1}]$$and$$A_{2n}=[0,\frac{1}{2n}]$$
It's clear that $\bigcup^\infty_{n=1} A_n\subset [0,2)$,and from intuition $\bigcup^\infty_{n=1} A_n=[0,2)$ seems correct, but how can I prove that?

Answer (score 1):

If $0 \leq x<2$ then $x \leq 2-\frac 1 {2n+1}$ for some positive integer $n$. In fact it is enough to take $n >\frac1  2(\frac 1 {2-x}-1)$. So $x \in A_{2n+1} \subseteq \bigcup_n A_n$.